# Room still run on Main Thread even though subscribed on IO Thread

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

This is the Room DAO I have.

```
@Dao
interface ProgramListDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(programList: List<Program>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM program_list")
    fun loadAll(): List<Program>
}
```

I'm trying to call this function

```
override fun isQuestionsRepoEmpty(): Observable<Boolean> = 
Observable.fromCallable({ questionsDao.loadAll().isEmpty() })
```

via

```
compositeDisposable.add(it.seedOptions()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                getView()?.let { decideActivityToOpen() }
            }))
```

where

```
fun seedOptions(): Observable<Boolean> {

    return optionsRepoHelper.isOptionsRepoEmpty().concatMap { isEmpty ->
        if (isEmpty) {    
            optionsRepoHelper.insertOptions(optionsList)
        } else
            Observable.just(false)
    }
}
```

However, this error came out when the isOptionsRepoEmpty() is called

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

I have read some posts on StackOverflow, and changed **Observable.just()** into **Observable.fromCallable()**, however it seems that the code still run on main thread.

How to solve it in this case?

**EDIT 1:**

This is how to replicate the exception

Repository: https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-kotlin-mvp-architecture

in **SplashPresenter.kt**, says I would only like to run **seedOption**

```
private fun feedInDatabase() = interactor?.let {
    compositeDisposable.add(it.seedOptions()
            .compose(schedulerProvider.ioToMainObservableScheduler())
            .subscribe({
                getView()?.let { decideActivityToOpen() }
            }))
}
```

But the app crashed because of this change, because the database run on main thread.

I have changed the this function from the original  `Observable.just()`  to `Observable.fromCallable()` , like so:

```
 override fun isOptionsRepoEmpty(): Observable<Boolean> = Observable.fromCallable({optionsDao.loadAll().isEmpty()})
```

Comment: where is your database instance ?

Comment: optionsRepoHelper is the Database instance

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace. The code shown should execute the `questionsDao.loadAll().isEmpty()` on the IO thread, so my assumption is that the exception comes from perhaps the initialization of the Room, not that query.

Comment: We also in the same issue,  have you solved the problem ?

Comment: Hi Anish, I solved it by **Invalidate Cache and Restart**, then run it on an actual Android phone.
Let me know if this helps.